# Multipage Forms - Capture page number on front-end

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore Forms to create a multi-page form. I need to capture the form page number each time a page is loaded, is it possible to capture this info on the front-end?

Comment: Can you try adding a hidden field and put that value from javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had considered doing this but it leaves a lot of room for error as content editors would need to add the step number to a field manually and attach to each page. Unless there is a way to have the page number generated by code on the backend and add a hidden input with that value to the bottom of each pae rendered? Any ideas?